# Light to Sound Device

Tags: audio, identification, light-sensor

I need a device that coverts blinking light to sound. What device would this be or called? Can this be done simply without soldering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without soldering the next best thing is breadboarding, which is for usually for prototyping but can be permanent if you're careful with not disconnecting anything from it. You will need an LDR (light dependent resistor) in a voltage divider and a transistor to power a piezo buzzer. Take this circuit and replace the LED with a piezo buzzer build-electronic-circuits.com/ldr-circuit-diagram There are plenty of tutorials on how to breadboard on YT.

It might also be worth seeing if you can just wire the piezo in parallel with the light

Comment: Can I find this online to order the parts?

Comment: For the transistor, the 2n2222 is a common one, the piezo buzzer, LDR, resistor kit, jumper wires can be bought on ebay, if you're feeling fancy you can also buy from a dedicated electronics supplier like RS-Online, Farnell, Digikey, Onecall, Mouser, etc, but you might not find everything in one place